# Initialise numpy array of unknown length

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to be able to 'build' a numpy array on the fly, I do not know the size of this array in advance.

For example I want to do something like this:

```
a= np.array()
for x in y:
     a.append(x)
```

Which would result in a containing all the elements of x, obviously this is a trivial answer. I am just curious whether this is possible?

Comment: What may be a more efficient approach is to allocate some large array, and double the size of it every time you reach capacity.

Comment: **What is the rule that tells you** the values to put into the array? **What is the rule that tells you** what the size of the final array will be, as you are getting the data? This question doesn't appear to describe an adequately clear problem statement.

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Build a Python list and convert that to a Numpy array. That takes amortized O(1) time per append + O(*n*) for the conversion to array, for a total of O(*n*).

```
    a = []
    for x in y:
        a.append(x)
    a = np.array(a)
```

Comment: Or better still: `a = np.array([x for x in y])`; or just `a = np.array(list(y))`

Answer (score 19):

You can do this:

```
a = np.array([])
for x in y:
    a = np.append(a, x)
```

Comment: That takes linear time per append.

Comment: This approach copies the array every append, which is O(sum(range(n))).  On my laptop, this method was 42 times slower than @larsman's method:  Building a list following larsmans method exactly takes me 1000 loops, best of 3: 1.53 ms per loop .  Following this method exactly takes me 10 loops, best of 3: 64.8 ms per loop.

Comment: Code should be readable, not fast, unless speed is your bottleneck. Why optimize code you'll run once?

Comment: Nice comment @AlexGaudio . I really didn't know that. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

Since y is an iterable I really do not see why the calls to append:

```
a = np.array(list(y))
```

will do and it's much faster:

```
import timeit

print timeit.timeit('list(s)', 's=set(x for x in xrange(1000))')
# 23.952975494633154

print timeit.timeit("""li=[]
for x in s: li.append(x)""", 's=set(x for x in xrange(1000))')
# 189.3826994248866
```

Answer (score 1):

For posterity, I think this is quicker:

```
a = np.array([np.array(list()) for _ in y])
```

You might even be able to pass in a generator (i.e. [] -> ()), in which case the inner list is never fully stored in memory.

---

Responding to comment below:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> y = range(10)
>>> a = np.array([np.array(list) for _ in y])
>>> a
array([array(<type 'list'>, dtype=object),
       array(<type 'list'>, dtype=object),
       array(<type 'list'>, dtype=object),
       array(<type 'list'>, dtype=object),
       array(<type 'list'>, dtype=object),
       array(<type 'list'>, dtype=object),
       array(<type 'list'>, dtype=object),
       array(<type 'list'>, dtype=object),
       array(<type 'list'>, dtype=object),
       array(<type 'list'>, dtype=object)], dtype=object)
```

Comment: I made a change here:  list(_)  and that worked great

Comment: To be clear @javadba, you don't need to do that--I'm sure there's some Pythonistas who would take offense :)

Comment: This is not a matter of style.  without the list(_) it does not even work at last for the case i have that y is an array itself

Comment: The OP says "which would result in `a` containing all the elements of x", so you def do need to do `list(_)`

Answer (score 1):

```
a = np.empty(0)
for x in y:
    a = np.append(a, x)
```

Comment: This won't work when x has a non-scalar dimension. For example, if x = np.ones((3,5)), it will fail.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a small utility function. (most answers above are good. I feel this looks nicer)

```
def np_unknown_cat(acc, arr):
  arrE = np.expand_dims(arr, axis=0)
  if acc is None:
    return arrE
  else:
    return np.concatenate((acc, arrE))
```

You can use the above function as the following:

```
acc = None  # accumulator
arr1 = np.ones((3,4))
acc = np_unknown_cat(acc, arr1)
arr2 = np.ones((3,4))
acc = np_unknown_cat(acc, arr2)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
list1 = []
size = 1
option = "Y"
for x in range(size):
    ele = input("Enter Element For List One : ")
    list1.append(ele)
while(option == "Y"):
    option = input("\n***Add More Element Press Y ***: ")
    if(option=="Y"):
        size = size + 1
        for x in range(size):
            ele = input("Enter Element For List Element : ")
            list1.append(ele)
            size = 1
    else:
        break;
print(list1)
```

**Take:**

```
list1 = []    # Store Array Element 
size = 1      # Rune at One Time 
option = "Y"  # Take User Choice
```

**Implementation:**

- For Loop at a range of size variable which runs one time because `size = 1`
- use While loop

  - take input from users if they want to add press "Y" else "N"
  - in the while loop use the if else statement if the option is "Y" then
    increase size with which helps run 2 time array because `size = size + 1`
    run another for loop at a range of size
  - else break