# Filter a numpy array if any list within it contains at least one value of a previous row

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array

```
b = np.array([[1,2], [3,4], [1,6], [7,2], [3,9], [7,10]])
```

Now, I want to do the following: I want to reduce b. The way I want to reduce it is that I look at the first element of b , i.e. `[1,2]` and based on that, I remove all the elements in b that contain at least a `1` or a `2`. In this case, I would eliminate `[1,6]` and `[7,2]`. Then I would look at `[3,4]` and eliminate those elements which contain at least `3` or `4`.

In practice, I start from the beginning of the list, and for each element, I delete the other elements containing one of its elements.

**My try**

```
for a in b:
    np.insert(b[~np.array([np.any((a==b)[j]) for j in range(len(b))])], 0,a, axis = 0)
```

Which sadly doesn't work!

This is what I tried, but it doesn't work and it is too lengthy. Any other ideas?

**Edit**
I think the main problem is that when I do `np.any((a==b)[j])` it only says True for those elements that have the first element equal to the first element of a, but doesn't say True when they are equal to the second element

**Edit 2**
Do you think this will work?

```
for index, a in enumerate(b):
    np.insert(b[~np.array([np.any(np.logical_or(a[0]==b, a[1]==b)[j]) for j in range(len(b))])], index, a,  axis = 0)
```

Comment: mmm yes, but the order in which you delete them is important! Imagine that the index of the rows is some sort of ranking. You want to keep those subarrays with only unique numbers, such that you have the highest (i.e. lowest) ranking

Comment: At the end the result should be `b = np.array([[1,2], [3,4], [7,10]])`. As you can see `[1,2]` survives over `[1,6]` and `[7,2]`, `[3,4]` survives `[3,9]` however `[7,2]` does not survive `[7,10]` since `[7,2]` was eliminated by `[1,2]`

Comment: What's the shape of array for your actual dataset?

Comment: I don't have it yet, but basically this list would be the result of the following: given a number (say 60k), I want to create all the combinations of numbers before it (i.e. [0,0], [1,1], [1,59k], etc..)

Comment: Then I want to do other stuff, but that is what the big number cames from

Comment: @Euler_Salter In that case it could make sense to ask (a new) question (or look for an existing one) how to avoid creating the unwanted "elements" in the first place. :)

Comment: Also I'm not sure if the title is better now, feel free to rollback the title in case it got more confusing than better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A trivial solution would be to use a normal Python loop:

```
b = np.array([[1,2], [3,4], [1,6], [7,2], [3,9], [7,10]])

final = []
seen = set()
for row in b.tolist():
    if seen.intersection(row):  # check if one element of the row has already been seen.
        continue
    else:
        # No item has been seen, so append this row and add the contents to the seen set.
        seen.update(row)
        final.append(row)

print(final)
# [[1, 2], [3, 4], [7, 10]]
```

I'm not sure if there's a good NumPy function for this kind of problem but it should be pretty fast with pure Python already.

Comment: Do you reckon it would be fast also for a list of the order of 10^12  elements?

Comment: I mean, relatively fast

Comment: I doubt you can even make a numpy array with 10^12 elements as this would require in the order of a 1000 GB of memory! You'd probably have to look at some array type that can cache parts to disk.

Comment: This is probably faster than doing it with numpy arrays as you don't know the length of the output. Appending in numpy happens in linear time iirc. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10121926/initialise-numpy-array-of-unknown-length also.

Comment: Really 10**12 elements? That's huge. That won't fit into any normal RAM because even a NumPy array consisting of `int64` would take 8 TB. A list of Python integers would take almost 35TB.

Comment: @MSeifert oh wow.. I think I'm trying to tackle a problem with way too many instances ahaha

Comment: Set is always faster! Sets are non-editable and don't index elements making them really efficient. Most of the operations on sets are O(1).

Comment: @Euler_Salter Yes, I think 8-10 TB (ignoring temporary copies) won't even fit on a regular hard-drive. So reducing the size is probably the only viable option.

Comment: It doesn't work! Try with `b = [[6,7], [0,10], [2,8], [2,2],[19,16], [6,2]]` !

Comment: @Euler_Salter What's wrong - it returns `[[6, 7], [0, 10], [2, 8], [19, 16]]` as expected?

Comment: @MSeifert quickly realised where the mistake in my code was, thanks! Now I will have to make a new question though ahah

Comment: @MSeifert if you want to help again..  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45844799/filter-numpy-array-if-elements-in-subarrays-are-repeated-position-wise-in-the-ot

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the dimensions of your data you might want to do something different but I in general the nice way to solve this is via indexing.
    import numpy as np

```
# Generate the data to work with
X = np.array([[1,2], [3,4], [1,6], [7,2], [3,9], [7,10]])

# Get the truth value is first value in the OR second value in the column
eq_idxs = np.logical_or(X == X[0, 0], X == X[0, 1])

# compress axis
eq_idxs = np.any(eq_idxs, axis=1)

#negate to get the remaining indexes
neq_idxs = np.logical_not(eq_idxs)

#Get the results
new_X = X[neq_idxs, :]
deleted_rows = X[eq_idxs, :]

print new_X
```

Outputs:

```
[[ 3  4]
 [ 3  9]
 [ 7 10]]
```

If you wish to repeat wrap it into a while(X.shape[0] > 0):

Comment: Does it work for you? I get an `IndexError` when I run your sample.

Comment: hm, it gives the wrong result now for `X = np.array([[1,2], [3,4], [1,6], [7,2], [3,9], [7,10]])` the `new_X` is `array([[ 7, 10]])`.

Comment: Works 100% now.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add a NumPy answer that relies on boolean indexing and (probably too many) reshapes and flattens.

```
import numpy as np
b = np.array([[1,2], [3,4], [1,6], [7,2], [3,9], [7,10]])

# flatten it for comparisons
b = b.ravel()
idx = 0
while idx < len(b) // 2:
    row = b[idx:idx+2]
    mask = np.zeros(b.shape, dtype=bool)
    np.logical_or(b[idx+2:] == row[0], b[idx+2:] == row[1], out=mask[idx+2:])
    b = b.reshape(-1, 2)  # reshape so "row" masking can be applied easily
    mask = mask.reshape(-1, 2).any(-1)
    b = b[~mask].ravel()  # ravel again after masking
    idx += 1
print(b.reshape(-1, 2))
# array([[ 1,  2],
#        [ 3,  4],
#        [ 7, 10]])
```

Probably this could be further improved using [`np.isin`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html) or similar but I don't have the time (right now) to improve this further.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a way (which was almost already in my edit), I will post it here just for the future, I think it is similar to some of the answers:

```
for index, a in enumerate(b):
    if index >= len(b) - 1:
        break
    else:
        b  = np.insert(b[~np.array([np.any(np.logical_or(a[0]==b, a[1]==b)[j]) for j in range(len(b))])], index, a,axis=0)
```

This should work