# Filter numpy array if elements in subarrays are repeated position-wise in the other subarrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Unluckily it is terribly similar to: [Filter a numpy array if any list within it contains at least one value of a previous row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45841160/filter-a-numpy-array-if-any-list-within-it-contains-at-least-one-value-of-a-prev/45841462?noredirect=1#comment78646997_45841462) which is a question I asked some minutes ago.

In this case I have a list

```
b = np.array([[1,2], [1,8], [2,3], [4,2], [5,6], [7,8], [3,3], [10,1]])
```

What I want to do is slightly different now.

I want to start at the beginning of the list and for each `subarray`. I want to check whether the element in position i (with respect to the `subarray`)  is encountered **in position i** also in other `subarrays`. Hence, removing all such elements.

For instance:

- Look at `[1,2]`: eliminate `[1,8]` cause 1 is in position 0, eliminate `[4,2]` cause 2 is in position 1. However do not eliminate `[10,1]` or `[2,3]` since 1 and 2 are in different positions.
- Look at `[2,3]` ,eliminate `[3,3]` since 3 is in position 1.
- Look at `[5,6],` nothing to eliminate.
- Look at `[7,8],` nothing to eliminate

So the result would be `b = np.array([[1,2], [2,3], [5,6], 7,8], [10,1]])`

**My Try**
As you can see in my previous post I tried different things. Now, I noticed that `a==b` gives a useful array, that could be used for filtering, but I can't quite decide how to put it all together.

Comment: maybe could use `b[~np.array([np.any((a==b)[j]) for j in range(len(b))])]` inside the loop `for a in b :` ?

Comment: By the time you get to `[7,8]`, `[1,8]` has already been seen, so `8` in second position is already recorded, why is `[7,8]` not eliminated?

Comment: because `[1,8]` has been eliminated by `[1,2]`! Since `[1,2]` has a `1` in position `0` and also `[1,8]` has a `1` in position `0`

Comment: Makes sense! But why is `[10, 1]`, not part of the result?

Comment: True that should be in the result!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Edit:

My initial solution doesn't consistently produce the result you're looking for, example at bottom.

So here's an alternative solution, which actually iterates through the rows as seems necessary:

```
ar = b.copy()
new_rows = []
while ar.shape[0]:
    new_rows.append(ar[0])
    ar = ar[(ar != ar[0]).all(axis=1)]
np.stack(new_rows)
Out[463]:
array([[ 1,  2],
       [ 2,  3],
       [ 5,  6],
       [ 7,  8],
       [10,  1]])
```

### Original Answer:

You can use `np.unique` with the argument `return_index=True` to identify rows which are the first to contain a value in a given column. You can then select these rows, in order, and do the same for the next column.

```
ar = b.copy()
num_cols = ar.shape[1]
for col in range(num_cols):
    ar = ar[np.sort(np.unique(ar[:, col], return_index=True)[1])]
ar
Out[30]: 
array([[ 1,  2],
       [ 2,  3],
       [ 5,  6],
       [ 7,  8],
       [10,  1]])
```

### Case where original fails:

Consider `ar = b[:, ::-1]`, with columns in reversed order.

Then,

```
num_cols = ar.shape[1]
    for col in range(num_cols):
        ar = ar[np.sort(np.unique(ar[:, col], return_index=True)[1])]
```

Gives

```
ar
Out[426]: 
array([[ 2,  1],
       [ 3,  2],
       [ 6,  5],
       [1,  10]])
```

missing the desired `[8, 7]` row.

Comment: One clarification: the elements in b are not in sorting order! (They do have an order but that comes from another manipulation). By sorting do you not risk to mixall of them up?

Comment: @Euler_Salter Nope – the array being sorted isn't the elements of b, but the array of their indices in b. So the sort just ensures that it picks them out in their initial order, as opposed to the smallest-to-largest order produced by `np.unique`.

Answer (score 1):

Your question and example need some clarifications (why is `[10, 1]` not part of the final answer? If a subarray gets eliminated, does that mean it doesn't contribute to eliminating any further subarrays?), but here's a first shot.  It's not very num-pythonic (or pythonic for that matter) but all it requires is a single loop through the larger array, with a map to keep track of the numbers you've seen, and a set for each number to keep track of the indices in which it's appeared.

```
final_arr = []
found_nums = {}
for subarray in array:
    found = False
    for i in xrange(len(subarray)):
        num = subarray[i]
        if num in found_nums:
            if i in found_nums[num]:
                found = True
                break
            else:
                found_nums[num].add(i)
        else:
            found_nums[num] = set([i])
    if not found:
        final_arr.append(subarray)
```

Comment: Apologies, I missed that one! An yes, if a subarray gets eliminated, then it doesn't contribute!