# Python: Add elements to second axis of numpy array in a loop

Tags: python, numpy

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10121926/initialise-numpy-array-of-unknown-length) suggests that we can use a Python list to add elements to it and convert it to numpy array using `np.array` with unknown length like this:

```
a = []
for x in y:
    a.append(x)
a = np.array(a)
```

Let's say `x` is a `numpy.ndarray` with shape (h,w) but h and w are unknown, how can we add elements to second axis of ndarray `a` in a loop to make `a` becomes (h,w,d) where d is the number of iterations?

I understand we can use `dstack` to add elements together to become (h,w,d) but I am not too sure how to do this in a loop.

Comment: Also play around with `np.stack`.  WIth the default `axis` value it behaves much like `np.array`, but you can specify other `axis` values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a similar thing, but with `x` as 2D numpy arrays.  That is, if you don't know the number of arrays ahead of time, you can collect them in a list and then convert them to a single 3D array in one step.  The code would look very similar to your example:

```
gen2d = (i*np.ones((2,2)) for i in range(random.randint(1, 10))) # a generator of unknown N

a = []
for x in gen2d:
    a.append(x)
a = np.dstack(a)

a.shape  # (2, 2, 7)
```