# How to create an empty numpy array with semi-specified dims?

Tags: python, arrays, json, numpy, object

I am trying to read data from a server like this:

```
with requests.Session() as s:
    data = {}
    r = s.get('https://something.com' , json = data ).json()
    training_set1 = np.empty([-1,4])
    training_set1[:,0] = r["o"]
    training_set1[:,1] = r["h"]
    training_set1[:,2] = r["l"]
    training_set1[:,3] = r["c"]
```

But I don't know the length of arrays, so I used `-1` then got this error message:

> ValueError: negative dimensions are not allowed

How can I fix this code? The response `r` is a JSON object:

```
{"t":[1322352000,1322438400], 
 "o":[123,123], 
 "h":[123,123], 
 "l":[123,123], 
 "c":[123,123]}
```

that I am trying to rearrange it to a numpy array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10121926/initialise-numpy-array-of-unknown-length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numpy arrays have fixed sizes. You cannot initialize a dynamic sized array. What you can do is use a list of lists and later convert the list to a numpy array.

Something like this should work assuming `r["x"]` is a list. (Untested code)

```
with requests.Session() as s:
    data = {}
    r = s.get('https://something.com' , json = data ).json()
    t_set1 = []
    t_set1.append(r["o"])
    t_set1.append(r["h"])
    t_set1.append(r["l"])
    t_set1.append(r["c"])
training_set1 = np.array(t_set1)
```

Edit: Edited for the order `"o","h","l",""c` after OP edited the question

Comment: It seems the order of data is wrong with using your code.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot declare a numpy array with an unknown dimension. But you can declare it in one single operation:

```
training_set1 = np.array([r["o"], r["o"], r["h"], r["l"]])
```

or even better:

```
training_set1 = np.array([r[i] for i in "oohl"])
```

Comment: Why do did you use `oohl` instead of `cohl`?

Comment: @user145959 You edited the question. Initially it was `oohl` and now its `ohlc`