# Python:Initialize and append data to 3d numpy array of unknown length beforehand

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, initialization

I want create 3d array with unknown length and append to the array as follows:

```
a = np.array([])
for n in range(1,3):
    data=np.full((2,3),n)
    a = np.append(a,data,axis=0)
print(a)
```

The expected output is:

```
[[[1,1,1]
  [1,1,1]]

 [[2,2,2]
  [2,2,2]]]
```

However, I got an error:

> ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 1 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 2 dimension(s)

How to declare an empty 3d numpy array with unknown length and append to it?

Comment: There isn't such a thing as an array of unknown length.  And no clear equivalent of list [], or list append.

Comment: @hpaulj : I have multiple nested loops with several if conditions. When an if condition is true, which is not known in advance, then I want to append the my 2d data to the 3d array. That is why the length in the 3rd dimension is unknown.

Comment: The shape of the final result might not be known before hand, but that's not the same as saying the shape of an existing array is unknown.   `np.array([]).shape` gives a result.  So does `np.array([[]]).shape` or `np.zeros((0,2,3)).shape`.

Comment: Yes. I mean that the shape of the final result is unknown beforehand.

Comment: `np.append` is a cover function for `np.concatenate`.  Especially when axis is provided all it does is `np.concatenate((a,b), axis=0)`.  That means you have to understand dimensions, and understand what `concatenate` expects.  There's no room for sloppiness here.

Answer (score 1):

It's better [performance-wise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10121926/initialise-numpy-array-of-unknown-length) (and easier) to create a list of your 2d arrays, then to call `numpy.stack()`:

```py
a = []
for n in range(1, 3):
    data = np.full((2, 3), n)
    a.append(data)
a = np.stack(a)
print(a)
print(a.shape) # <- (2, 2, 3)
```

You can also append to the list (`a`) 2d arrays in a list-of-lists structure (meaning, they don't have to be numpy arrays) and call `np.stack()` on that "list of lists of lists", would work too.